# AngularJS multiple dynamic directives binding

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm new to AngularJS, and I'm just too dumb to get this working.

I'm trying to generate

- a list of panels (dynamically)
- when I click on the panel header, panel body will expand / collapse
- when the particular panel body collapse, I want to create a table and bind some data into it

Here is my code

```
    <script>
    var app = angular.module('TestApp', []);
    app.controller('TestCtrl', function ($scope) {
        $scope.parents = [
            { id: '1', name: 'Test Parent 1', count: '2' },
            { id: '2', name: 'Test Parent 2', count: '3' },
            { id: '3', name: 'Test Parent 3', count: '1' }
        ];

        $scope.parent_click = function (parent) {
            var children_list = [
            { id: '1', parent_id: '1', name: 'Test Child 1' },
            { id: '2', parent_id: '1', name: 'Test Child 2' },
            { id: '3', parent_id: '2', name: 'Test Child 3' },
            { id: '4', parent_id: '2', name: 'Test Child 4' },
            { id: '5', parent_id: '2', name: 'Test Child 5' },
            { id: '6', parent_id: '3', name: 'Test Child 6' }
            ];
            var directive_name = 'clschild_' + parent.id;
            app.directive(directive_name, function () {
                var child_html = '<div class="panel-body"> \
                    <table ng-attr-id="tblchild_'+ parent.id + '" class="table table-hover"> \
                        <thead> \
                            <tr> \
                                <td>Name</td> \
                            </tr> \
                        </thead> \
                        <tbody> \
                            <tr ng-repeat="child in children"> \
                                <td>{{child.name}}</td> \
                            </tr> \
                        </tbody> \
                    </table> \
                </div>';
                return {
                    template: child_html,
                    link: function (scope) {
                        scope.$apply(function () { scope.children = children_list; });
                    }
                }
            });
        };
    });

</script>
<div ng-app="TestApp" ng-controller="TestCtrl">
    <div class="panel panel-default" ng-repeat="parent in parents">
        <div class="panel-heading clearfix">
            <a id="testtest" data-toggle="collapse" ng-href="#divchild_{{parent.id}}" ng-click="parent_click(parent);" class="pull-left" style="padding-top: 7.5px;">{{parent.name}}</a>
        </div>
        <div ng-attr-id="divchild_{{parent.id}}" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="clschild_{{parent.id}}">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    aaa
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I would like to bind the data to the correspond parent's panel body. How can I achieve that?

Edit:
Problem - Now when I click the panel header, the panel body expanded but only showed "aaa". I can't get the children list bound to the panel body.

Thanks

Comment: Hello there, I've edited my question. No my toggle doesn't work the data and template is not binding to the panel body.

Comment: You cannot create directive inside the controller like that.

Comment: Hello, so is there any other way I can achieve this? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

So approach could be here to track the clicked parent id and filter the children list in `ng-repeat` by passing that clicked parent id.

```
    $scope.clicked_parent = 0;
    $scope.parents = [
        { id: '1', name: 'Test Parent 1', count: '2' },
        { id: '2', name: 'Test Parent 2', count: '3' },
        { id: '3', name: 'Test Parent 3', count: '1' }
    ];

    $scope.children_list = [
      { id: '1', parent_id: '1', name: 'Test Child 1' },
      { id: '2', parent_id: '1', name: 'Test Child 2' },
      { id: '3', parent_id: '2', name: 'Test Child 3' },
      { id: '4', parent_id: '2', name: 'Test Child 4' },
      { id: '5', parent_id: '2', name: 'Test Child 5' },
      { id: '6', parent_id: '3', name: 'Test Child 6' }
    ];

    $scope.isParentTagClicked = false;
    $scope.set_parent_id = function(_id){
      $scope.isParentTagClicked = !$scope.isParentTagClicked;
      if ($scope.isParentTagClicked){
        $scope.clicked_parent = _id; 
      }else{
        $scope.clicked_parent     = 0;
      }
    };
```

And declare the view like

```
<div class="panel panel-default" ng-repeat="parent in parents">
        <div class="panel-heading" ng-click="set_parent_id(parent.id)">{{parent.name}}</div>
        <div class="panel-body" ng-repeat="child in children_list" ng-show="child.parent_id == clicked_parent" ng-if="child.parent_id == parent.id">
          {{child.name}}
 </div>
</div>
```